# Как вставлять в заготовленный текст имя?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть заготовленный текст(Который указывается в самом юнити). Нужно, чтобы в этом тексте вставлялось имя игрока. Как это сделать?

```
_textDialog.text = text[_textIndex]; // Например "Привет {name}!". 
//Также есть и текст БЕЗ употребления имени: "Привет друг"
```

То, что мне нужно(Пример) в выводе: `Привет ИМЯ!`

Как создаётся текст:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _textDialog.text ="Привет " + text[_textIndex] +"!";

Comment: @Qwer Извините, наверное я был не сильно точен. Дополню вопрос

Comment: `_textDialog.text = text[0].Replace("{name}!", myName);`

Comment: @Yaroslav Помогло. Оставьте ответ, чтобы я его отметил правильным

Comment: _textDialog.text = text[_textIndex].Replace("{name}", "Вася Пупкин");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты указал, что вставлять, а откуда брать ты не указал. Да и вообще, стоит написать вот так

```
_textDialog.text = text[0].Replace("{name}",Name);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    private string BuildArgs(string message, params string[] args)
    {
       string temp = message;
    
       int lastIndex = 0;
       for (int iterator = 0; iterator < args.Length; iterator++)
       {
            lastIndex = temp.IndexOf("%s", lastIndex);
    
            if (lastIndex == -1)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    
            temp = temp.Remove(lastIndex, 2);
            temp = temp.Insert(lastIndex, args[iterator]);
        }

        return temp;
    }
```

EXAMPLE:

```
string message = "Hi, %s. how are you?";
string insertArg = "Vova";
Debug.Log(BuildArgs(message, insertArg));
```

Comment: А в чем преимущество перед риплейсом?

Comment: @AndrewStop_RU_war_in_UA в том, чтобы не тупеть от использования готовых решений.

Comment: то есть никакого и просто лишний код в проекте в который могли забраться баги и который просто занимает лишнее место. Вероятно твои проэкты долго компилируются, раз уж не хочешь. тупеть от готовых решений) А почему C#? Может лучеш сразу на перфокартах бинарным кодом программировать? Че ж решил тупеть от использования готовых решений? :)